# Randomized Parameters Using System()?

Tags: c++, sat

I am attempting to try some randomized parameters for minisat while calling the program using `system()`. I've never done anything like this before and have to admit I am pretty lost.

For example I can do like:

```
system("minisat -luby -rinc=1.5 <dataset here>")
```

How can I randomize it to be `-luby` or `-no-luby` and randomize the `1.5` value for `-rinc`?

Comment: What values are valid for the -rinc?

Comment: Also, by system do you mean the function `system("command")`?

Comment: Yeah system("command") is what I meant. Like I said I just discovered this command and new to it haha. Thanks for clearing that up. I appreciate it!

Comment: I added an answer that has a completely randomized string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need construct the command dynamically with variables.

```
bool luby = true;  // if you want -no-luby, set it to be false
double rinc = 1.5;  // set it to be other values

char command[1024];
std::string luby_str = (luby ? "luby" : "no-luby");
std::snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "minisat -%s -rinc=%f", luby_str.c_str(), rinc);
system(command);
```

Just as @RemyLebeau pointing out, the C++ style should be better.

```
std::string command;
std::ostringstream os;
os << "minisat -" << luby_str << " -rinc=" << rinc;
system(command.c_str());
```

Comment: I would suggest not using a `char[]` for `command`. Use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) instead to build up the command line dynamically as needed, and then pass it to `system()` when ready, eg: `std::ostringstream command;
command << "minisat -" << luby ? "luby" : "no-luby" << " -rinc=" << rinc << " " << ...; system(command.str().c_str());`

Comment: Ok thanks guys I appreciate the suggestions! Im going to try some of this out and see what I come up with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, the C++ style is better.

Comment: No need to use a stringstream, you can simply use the `+` operator on two `std::string`s.

Comment: @Steve For C++03, there's no concise method to convert `double` to `string`.

Answer (score 1):

system is only a normal function that receive a c-style string as the parameter. You can construct the string by yourself.

```
bool luby = true;
double rinc = 1.5;
system((std::string("minisat -")+(luby?"luby":"no-luby")+" -rinc="+std::to_string(rinc)).c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can try using a random string command generator like this, to create a randomized command:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <string>

std::string getCommand()
{
    std::string result = "minisat ";
    srand(time(0));
    int lubyflag = rand() % 2; //Not the best way to generate random nums
                               //better to use something from <random>
    if (lubyflag == 1)
    {
        result += "-luby ";
    } else 
    {
        result += "-no-luby ";
    }
    double lower_bound = 0; //Now were using <random>
    double upper_bound = 2; //Or whatever range 
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(lower_bound,upper_bound);
    std::default_random_engine re;
    double rinc_double = unif(re);
    result += "-rinc=" + rinc_double;
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    std::string command = getCommand();
    system(command.c_str());
}
```

If you want all control, do this:

```
bool flaga = false;
double valueb = 1.5;
system(std::string("ministat " + ((flaga) ? "-luby " : "-no-luby ") + 
    "rinc= " + std::to_string(valueb)).c_str());
```